# What is the command line program to seed an already downloaded torrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, rtorrent

So, I'm finished with downloading Ubuntu 12.04 torrent. I used rtorrent for that. After it's finished, I closed the rtorrent. Now, I still has the torrent file and I want to seed it without redownloading the iso file.

How can I accomplish that with a command line program? uTorrent can do this kind of thing easily, but I want a simple command line.

I tried rtorrent as well as aria2c, both didn't work out my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it with exactly the same command that you started the torrent download with. This means you still need to have the .torrent file handy.

Comment: This works because the bittorrent client does a hash check of the downloaded data, recognizes that the download is complete, and automatically starts uploading, correct?

Comment: That's right. :)

Comment: Actually, it works! I forgot to ignore the rtorrent unfriendly-seed-config. But aria2c prompted to redownload and overwrite the downloaded data before it can seed the torrent.

Comment: Simply adding a session directory to rtorrent is the very 1st thing to do when setting it up, and makes the whole thing a non-issue.

Comment: All right, thanks. I'll read about rtorrent session things.